# Reference Point not visible on control bar in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator

What's happened to the Reference point in AI CC?  I'm in process of switching AI's and the Reference point was always available on the dashboard in CS4 when I highlighted an asset on the artboard.

Now it appears to placed in the Scale tool.

I can highlight some assets and the Reference point appears on the Dashboard, then for other assets, I have to open the Scale tool?

I attempted to create a keyboard shortcut but couldn't find it (Reference Point) in Preferences to create one? (After I get creative, I get to the details and like to note all reference points.)

Does anyone have a solution for me? Or am I missing something.  I've tried various views but still baffled.

---

Dash = top of board that provides options when you highlight any vector, guide, image on Artboard (Under Menu). Reference point = is the square box containing squares on all corners, centre point, mid lines points = all of which can be highlighted to provide you with the XY coordinates of your assets, guides, images etc on the Artboard.

I have just noticed that in img in which Ref point is available that the highlighted item is a group.  However, when I tried to repeat by ungrouping and grouping again, Reference point not available!

I hope this explains my dilemma.

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you are referring to. Dashboard in Illustrator? Reference point? For a symbol? Or do you mean the center point?

Comment: Hi Metis, 

Thanks.

Dash = top of board that provides options when you highlight any vector, guide, image on Artboard.
Reference point = is the square box containing squares on all corners, centre point, mid lines points = all of which can be highlighted to provide you with the XY coordinates of your assets, guides, images etc on the Artboard.

I have just noticed that in img in which Ref point is available that the highlighted item is a group.  However, when I tried to repeat by ungrouping and grouping again, Reference point not available!

Comment: Are you by any chance in Isolation mode? (and thanks @Cai)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference point is visible in the "Transform" panel.  Press Shift-F8 to view the transform panel.

---

Keep in mind the reference point is the reference point *for some particular action*.  So it's not really a global thing (i.e. it's not relevant for all tools, only a couple).

And really it's not relevant for any *tools*, since if you're clicking and dragging to resize (or whatever) you've already implicitly chosen your reference point (and you can hold down shift and/or option as applicable).

It's only relevant for typed-in changes to the object size (in the Transform panel) or the "scale" dialog.

Comment: Yes, thanks Wildcard.  My point was that in CS4 the location point of an object was visible on CTRL panel. Now in Cloud 2017 not.  Hence the two images with one CS4 one CC 2017.

Answer (score 0):

The origin point will not be visible when you select individual objects which are *within a group* because the **group** defines the origin, not the objects within that group.

Same holds to for isolation mode in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I just clicked on the toolbar toggle switch on the far right of the top toolbar, unchecked the 'Shape' panel and once that was gone, the Transform panel expanded and the 9-point reference box is there now along with the X, Y, Height and Width boxes.

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly not showing because of the UI scaling - Preferences>User Interface.
On the larger settings it doesn't show, but change it to the smallest setting and it shows.